# How to automatically turn on keyboard backlight at night and automatically turn it off during daytime?

Tags: 22.04, keyboard-backlight

Is there any way (maybe with a systemd service that will run the appropriate commands) to automatically turn off the keyboard backlight in the morning and will automatically turn it on at night?

I am using Kubuntu 22.04 in a Dell Latitude 5400.

There is no light sensor.
I want to manually set the time.

The other option is to get the time from redshift/KDE Night mode.

---

I see the following output after enabling the systemd timer for the manual mode.

```
$ systemctl --user enable --now keyboard-backlight-evening-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.timer
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
 
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.

$ systemctl status keyboard-backlight-evening-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.timer
Unit keyboard-backlight-evening-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.timer could not be found.
```

Comment: It depends on if there is a light sensor. Or you can do it by time.

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 1):

#### New solution: KDE Night color sync

You can listen for the night color activating, and have the backlight follow it.

1. Set things up with the following:

   ```bash
   sudo apt install brightnessctl
   sudo usermod -aG input ${USER}
   sudo usermod -aG video ${USER}
   reboot
   ```
2. Note the output of `brightnessctl --list`
3. Paste in `~/.config/systemd/user/keyboard-backlight-kde-night-color-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.service`

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=Sync keyboard backlight to night color

   [Service]
   Exec=%h/.local/share/keyboard-backlight-kde-night-color-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.sh

   [Install]
   WantedBy=plasma-kwin_wayland.service
   ```
4. `~/.local/share/keyboard-backlight-kde-night-color-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.sh`

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   dbus-monitor "type='signal',sender='org.kde.NightColor',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',path=/ColorCorrect,member=PropertiesChanged" |
     sed -nu '/string "running"/{N;s/.*\(true\|false\).*/\1/;p}' |
     while read -r line; do
       target_brightness=0
       if [ "$line" = 'true' ]; then
         target_brightness=30
       fi
       brightnessctl --device='your device here' set "$target_brightness"
     done
   ```
5. `chmod +x ~/.local/share/keyboard-backlight-kde-night-color-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.sh`
6. Make you sure you changed the `'your device here'` part
7. `systemctl --user daemon-reload`
8. `systemctl --user enable --now keyboard-backlight-kde-night-color-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.service`

#### Alterantive solution: Manual timer

You can set up a timer to automatically set the brightness based on time:

1. Do the same setup steps as the other solution
2. Note the output of `brightnessctl --list`
3. Paste in `~/.local/share/keyboard-backlight-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.sh`

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   # Handle AccuracySec=1
   sleep 2

   # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067658/10477326
   until_sunrise=$((($(date -f - +%s- <<<06:00$' tomorrow\nnow')0)%86400))
   until_sunset=$((($(date -f - +%s- <<<18:00$' tomorrow\nnow')0)%86400))

   if [ $until_sunrise -lt $until_sunset ]; then # sunrise is closer 
     echo 'Backlight on at nighttime'
     brightnessctl --device='your device here' set 30
   else # sunset is closer
     echo 'Backlight off at daytime'
     brightnessctl --device='your device here' set 0
   fi
   ```
4. Make you sure you changed both `'your device here'` parts
5. `chmod +x ~/.local/share/keyboard-backlight-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.sh`
6. Paste in `~/.config/systemd/user/keyboard-backlight-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.service`

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=Sync keyboard backlight

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=%t/.local/share/keyboard-backlight-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.sh
   ```
7. `~/.config/systemd/user/keyboard-backlight-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.timer`

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=Sync keyboard backlight to time

   [Timer]
   OnCalendar=6,18:00
   OnStartupSec=1

   [Install]
   WantedBy=timers.target
   ```
8. `systemctl --user daemon-reload`
9. `systemctl --user enable --now keyboard-backlight-sync-askubuntu-1503945-1004020.timer`

You can also use `/etc/systemd/system` instead to avoid `sudo` or group complications.

Comment: Suppose, the computer is in sleep mode at 6 PM, when systemd is supposed to call the script and I open the computer at 6:10 PM. Will the keyboard lights still turn on?

Comment: You might want to use the second solution, which should turn on even if the computer goes to sleep. Thank you for pointing out the sudo problem. Even if the first solution needs `Persistent=true` to be added, I'm now worried that there's a bug where both of the timers activate at the same time.

Comment: I will try the KDE Night color tomorrow and get back to you. While the KDE Night color will work in KDE (if everything goes well), it will not work with GNOME or XFCE or something else. Perhaps a solution based on redshift/geoclue will work for everyone.

Comment: I brought back the old solution combined with new ideas to fix the bug. It would work for GNOME or XFCE. It works beside redshift, but too bad redshift doesn't give us any DBus signal to listen to

Comment: Now the manual entry shows `The unit files have no installation config` similar to what I have posted by editing my question. I will try everything using `/etc/systemd/` and get back to you.

Comment: I'm very sorry that I missed the timers.target part when copying and pasting from my file to here

Comment: Unfortunately the second part of the answer still does not seem to work. I cannot try the first part as I moved from KDE to Cinnamon.